# Any samples of MVC2 + Silverlight 4? Visual Studio 2010 does not organize the files correctly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, silverlight

I create a SL4 Application and then I say I want to create a MVC site in addition. But instead of create a VIEW and putting showing the SL4 object there and creating a empty MVC type Default page... it just creates a SilverlightApplicationTestPage.aspx in the root!

Does anyone know any small sample code anywhere that shows how to set up various .xap files within a MVC app. It should be simple. (I want to put the MVC2 app into Azure once I get this working)

Comment: Maybe I am thinking about it wrong.. Should a page in a MVC2 JUST be a plain html page perhaps?  If I am not passing any parameters to the SL4 app I just it can live in a html page that has nothing to do with MVC2. right?

ASP.NET MVC2 is all about web sites and nothing to do hosting a object tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test page that Visual Studio creates for your Silverlight app just contains some javascript to determine if SL is installed or not as well as a div that references your xap file. You could put the javascript at the top of your MVC page and put the div wherever you want on that page to embed the silverlight object.